# Super weird error when handling strings

Tags: c++, string, function, binary, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a function that converts a binary number (string) into a decimal one (int). The weird part about the code below is that **when the line "//cout << index << endl;" is not commented out, it works! WHY D:?**

Output when commented out:

> 1651929379

Output when active:

> 7 192 Program ended with exit code: 0

**Here's the entire program:**

```
//
//  testish.cpp
//  Egetskojs
//
//  Created by Axel Kennedal on 2014-02-13.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Axel Kennedal. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int BinaryToDecimal(string & binaryString);

int main(){

    string binary = "11000000";
    int decimal = BinaryToDecimal(binary);
    cout << decimal << endl;




    return 0;
}


int BinaryToDecimal(string & binaryString){
    int solution;

    if (binaryString == "0") solution = 0;
    if (binaryString == "1") solution = 1;

    int index = binaryString.length() - 1; //The index of the last (rightmost) bit in the string
    //cout << index << endl;

    int currentBit = 0; //The exponent to be used when calculating the value of a bit

    for (; index >= 0; index--) {
        if (binaryString.at(index) == '1') {
            solution += pow(2, currentBit);
        }
        //Else: nothing happens
        currentBit++;
    }

    //Done!
    return solution;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have *undefined behavior* in the `BinaryToDecimal`, because the variable `solution` may be used uninitialized.

Uninitialized local variables will have indeterminate values (i.e. their values will be seemingly random).

Comment: Allright thanks :)! But how come it works when I use that cout?

Answer (score 0):

As Joachim said, your solution variable is uninitialized, so when the string is neither "0" nor "1", you may get strange behavior (e.g. integer overflows) in your += operation. I guess that the fact that it works when the output is active is due to some weird side-effect of the output instructions causing some register to contain 0, and that register being the source of the value for `solution`. It might be enlightening to know what your compiler settings are for this, and to look at the assembler code for this part of your code.
You could replace:

```
int BinaryToDecimal(string & binaryString){
    int solution;

    if (binaryString == "0") solution = 0;
    if (binaryString == "1") solution = 1;
    ...
```

with:

```
int BinaryToDecimal(string & binaryString){
    int solution = 0;
    ...
```

Since the special case handling you do is elegantly handled by your loop after.